# Next-auth: getSession returns null when post request body or header is set

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to implement post request in nextjs, I am using `next-auth` package. When I made get request that don't require setting header or body the `await getSession({ req });` on the server return the correct data, but when I add a header or body like in a post request it returns null.

```
    const response = await fetch("/api/shops", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        shopName: shopName,
        description: description
      }),
    });
```

When I remove the header and body

```
    const response = await fetch("/api/shops", {
      method: 'POST',
      // headers: {
      //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // },
      // body: JSON.stringify({
      //   shopName: shopName,
      //   description: description
      // }),
    });
```

It return the expected value.

The [...nextauth].js file looks like this

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import mongoDbClient from "../../../lib/mongodb";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const db = (await mongoDbClient).db(process.env.MONGODB_DBNAME);
        const usersCollection = db.collection("users");

        const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
          email: credentials.email,
        });

        if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(credentials.password, user.password)) {
          delete user.password;
          return user;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token.user) {
        session.user = token.user;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

I expect that this should work regardless of if the body/header is set or not but it isn't.

Edit: I just found that if I delete the body object from the request it works

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const body = { ...req.body };
  delete req.body;
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized" });
    return;
  }

  ...
}
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this was to set bodyParser and false, at the top of all api handlers

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized" });
    return;
  }

  ...
}
```